# Scanning Switch for IP and VLAN Details

Tags: python, sockets, vlan

I've got a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian.
I was hoping to be able to use it to pull a few details from a switch using one of the ports. Similar to the Fluke LinkRunner.

I'm using Python (which I've never used before) and can only get the port IP.

I've done a fair bit of reading on various forums, but can't seem to find anything about pulling VLAN details.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

This get's me the assigned IP, and that's as far as I've got.

So, my question would be, is it actually possible to pull the Switch IP and VLAN details from a port on the switch?

Comment: It would depend on the switch. It's not something there's a standard way to do.

Comment: The switch I'm trying to use/test at the minute is a Cisco Catalyst 2960.

Comment: You can query the 2960's MAC, VLAN, LLDP, CDP and other tables by using SNMP or the console interface.